# How can write Dockerfile to start a webserver and curl it for some requirements

Tags: tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I'd like to use this dockerfile naively.

> ```
> FROM test/tomcat
> ENV CATALINA_HOME /tomcat
> RUN ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh start
> RUN wget localhost:8080/Writer/WriterServlet
> ```

The result is as follows certainly

> ```
> docker build --no-cache=true - < Dockerfile
> Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
> Sending build context to Docker daemon
> Step 0 : FROM test/tomcat
>  ---> 2a85ccb3dd07
> Step 1 : ENV CATALINA_HOME /tomcat
>  ---> Running in 76872d1acdd5
>  ---> 30ad1fe832d6
> Removing intermediate container 76872d1acdd5
> Step 2 : RUN ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh start
>  ---> Running in 5947560a3428
> Tomcat started.
>  ---> ea670dd1d3ff
> Removing intermediate container 5947560a3428
> Step 3 : RUN wget localhost:8080/Writer/WriterServlet
>  ---> Running in 6aa5c9be8569
> --2014-12-19 03:08:16--  http://localhost:8080/Writer/WriterServlet
> Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
> Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
> Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
> 2014/12/19 11:08:16 The command [/bin/sh -c wget localhost:8080/Writer/WriterServlet] returned a non-zero code: 4
> ```

In this case, tomcat offer some interface to write a file, so I need to build through the tomcat server.

Maybe because the wget can't wait tomcat to start up.

Or because docker's layered container structure cause that when in step 3(wget), the tomcat down again.

So my question in summary is, can I write a docker build to keep some process run together for the interactive requirements?

Comment: Have you tried:`RUN ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh start && wget localhost:8080/Writer/WriterServlet` or if it is an timeing porblem you could in the first step try something like this `RUN ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh start && sleep XX && wget localhost:8080/Writer/WriterServlet` <- Not pretty good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker file build steps do not maintain a running container or systme. Each line makes a change to the file system, docker stores the changes to the file system only. Any processes that are started are discarded.

Docker can only start long running processes when a container is run (not when a container is being built). You need to use ENTRYPOINT or CMD to call a custom script at container startup. This script will start tomcat and run the wget and make any changes needed before starting a long running process such as a tail on tomcat logs.